# StatusBar overlaps app's toolbar and the toolbar is gone on Android API 30+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-statusbar, android-fullscreen

I have a app's toolbar issue on Android API 30+. The device's status bar overlap my app's toolbar and the toolbar is gone. This problem does not occur on device with API below 30 (29, 28, 27, ...). I searched through *Stackoverflow* and did not found any working solution for my case.

I tried `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);` it brings the toolbar back and show the app in full-screen mode but the device's status bar and bottom navigation bar overlap (half transparent) the app's content.

What I want is the devices's status bar and bottom navigation bar are not overlap with the app's content. They can appear or disappear.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />

        <!-- Loading box -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/boxProgress"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/loading_box_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/loading_box_size"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@drawable/background_round_corner" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/box_margin_medium"
                android:indeterminate="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/progressBar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/label_status_loading"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Order drawer (slide from right) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**toolbar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="36dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/box_margin_bottom_small"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarIndicator"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:padding="@dimen/box_padding_small"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Application Theme**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">...</style>
```

Comment: try `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in root layout,

Comment: @C.F.G I tried it but it does not work. However, I found that I accidently ```setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)``` in *MainActivity.kt*. I remove it and it works!. I updated the answer below. Thank you for trigger me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it works!! In the past I used to add the following code to `onCreate()` in *MainActivity.kt*.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
   this.window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
}
```

After I removed it, everything is back to what it should be. Thank you *C.F.G* for trigger me about `fitSystemWindows` property.